# Difference in average of field values roll-up look up relationship

Tags: apex, soql

I got a requirement like to calculate average in account based on particular record type of case. My requirement is:

I have a field called ARP in account currency. I want to calculate overall average of ARP field in particular record type called customer order whether Case details either new or add-on.

So I'm trying write a trigger a trigger.

ARPu field in case is a formula currency data type.In account also i had created Arpu name with currency(5,2).

> But i am getting a difference in average. For sample scenario: 41.51 &
>   94.51
>
> Actual average for above scenario like 67.5.But, i am getting 139.51

```
 trigger ForARPU on case (after delete, after insert) 
 {  
 Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName ='Customer_Order'].Id;
List<Account> Accountstoupdate =new List<Account>();
List<Case> CaseIDs = new List<Case>();
for (Case s : Trigger.new)
{
    if(s.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId && s.Case_Details__c =='New Subscription' || s.Case_Details__c =='Add On' ) 
    {
        CaseIDs.add(s);

    }
}
set<Id> setCaseIds = new set<Id>();
for(Case c : [SELECT Id,ARPU__c,accountId FROM Case WHERE Id IN :CaseIDs]){
    setCaseIds.add(c.AccountId);
}
List<Account> MList = [select Id,name,ARPU__c  from Account where id =:setCaseIds];
Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
[SELECT AccountId Id, AVG(ARPU__c) average FROM Case
 WHERE AccountId = :MList
 GROUP BY AccountId]);
Decimal decimalRevenue = 0;
For(account a1: MList) {
    if(results.get(a1.Id) != null) {
    a1.ARPU__c = (Decimal)results.get(a1.Id).get('average');
    Accountstoupdate.add(a1);
}
}
if(Accountstoupdate.size()>0) {
    update Accountstoupdate;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using SUM(), so of course you're getting the total. If you want the average value per account, use AVG() instead:

```
Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
    [SELECT AccountId Id, AVG(ARPU__c) average FROM Case
     WHERE AccountId = :MList
     GROUP BY AccountId]);
```

Also, I use the Id alias trick to use a map, which lets us change the for loop:

```
for(Account a1: MList) {
    if(results.get(a1.Id) != null) {
        a1.ARPU__c = (Decimal)results.get(a1.Id).get('average');
        Accountstoupdate.add(a1);
    }
}
```

As an aside, the object type of an SOQL aggregate function is already a Decimal. There's no need to convert it to a string and then parse it back in to a decimal.

Comment: Hey @sfdcfox i am still facing the issue.I had updated my code in question with your suggestions.But i got slight difference i don't know why.I had created a sample case with above criteria ARPU is 30.51 but in account it's updated with 34.00.

Comment: Hey I got the fix.Thanks really you teach me something today Brian Fear.Because really you save my time as well as i learned something.thanks once again for sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You need to group it by accountId

```
List <aggregateResult> groupedResults = [select sum(ARPU__c)aver from case where AccountId =: MList group By AccountId];
```

and then based on accountId need to update the average. Currently you are doing average of all linked cases.

Comment: Still facing the same issue.like i had created a case with the above criteria and ARPU would be in case is $52.51 and in account it is showing $56.00.@Tushar Sharma

Comment: @Pavantej try with inner query. Or share your updated code.

Comment: Updated aggregate query above code as you mentioned @Tushar Sharma

Comment: @Pavantej you need to get sum for only current Account you are fetching first record and just updating it. You need to fetch based on account id.

Comment: Hey can you post the code.It would really because i am not familiar about aggregate queries.@Tushar Sharma